# Reference previous value in data.table calculation

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to reference the value in a previous calculation during the current one. I've tried using shift(), but it does not work when using the same variable.

```
 x  
 1  
 2  
 3  
 5  
 1
```

I want to do something like this. I want shift(z) to refer to the previously calculated value of the same variable. If I run this, I get an error saying that object 'z' was not found.

```
dt[, z := 0.1 * x + 0.2 * shift(z)]
```

How do I do this without writing a loop?

Comment: pipe it: `dt[, z := 0.1 * x + 0.2 ][, z:= z * shift(z)]`

Comment: I want it to start with zero for the first one. Then use the value from the previous row. So, (0.1*1 + 0.2*0) would be first row. The second would be (0.1*2 + 0.2*0.1(The value from the first row)).

Comment: YOLO, doesn't that mess with the order of operations? I want to multiply by the previous value of z before doing the addition.

Comment: desired output unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a logic with `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>% 
  mutate(z = tail(accumulate(x, ~ .y * 0.1 + 0.2 * .x, .init = 0), -1))
#  x       z
#1 1 0.10000
#2 2 0.22000
#3 3 0.34400
#4 5 0.56880
#5 1 0.21376
```

---

Or the same logic with `Reduce`

```
dt[, z := tail(Reduce(function(x, y)  y * 0.1 + 0.2 * x, x, 
     init = 0, accumulate = TRUE), -1)]
```

Comment: while reading your solutions sometimes I feel like I know nothing.

Comment: What do the .x and .y parts mean?

Comment: @YOLO This one is a bit tricky, but you will get used to it.  It is just understanding that recursive logic

Comment: @buckbeak  Here `.x` refers to the value that gets updated and `.y` the actual values.  You can check it by `dt %>% mutate(z = tail(accumulate(x, ~ .x, .init = 0), -1))` `dt %>% mutate(z = tail(accumulate(x, ~ .y, .init = 0), -1))`

Comment: @buckbeak  If you check the `?accumulate` the description is `# .x is the accumulating value
1:10 %>% accumulate(~ .x)
# .y is element in the list`